# how do i open up a zipfile of a subtitle and embed it onto a video?

Tags: zip, subtitle

would someone please give me explicit step by step instructions how to install an external subtitle onto a foreign video that 
i will play on SMPlayer. i know how to download the zip file from google and once the text version of the file is in my Download file i know how to drag and drop that text onto the video. I just don't know the intervening steps very well.
Somewhere along the line i seem to recall using a text editor...The hardest part was getting that text from the text editor into my Download file
Please dont tell me to open it up like any other zip file because i have no idea how to do that.
thanks

Comment: What file are you trying to use exactly? We can't help you if we don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: let's say i want to watch a foreign-language movie and i download the video through my torrent client.Unfortunately, the video may not have an embedded subtitle.therefore, have to download a zipfile

Comment: Now, i need to have step by step explicit instructions on precisely what to do after i download the zipfile of the subtitle and opened it up in the archive. Precisely, how do i get the text in the zipfile open. and once the text is revealed in Gedit text editor, then how is it tranfered to my download file? That is, just what do i have to do to get it into my download file. From there, i know what to do

Comment: That depends on what's in the zipfile..

Comment: a foreign-language movie's English subtitles. just the printed text that will have to be embedded onto the movie video

Comment: a printed text of a movies's subtitles that will have to be embedded onto a video. That is what is in the zip file. zip files like these are usually just downloaded from Google and up in the archive. what happens next? that is the question! 1-how do i get file in the archive to open so that the text is shown in gedit and 2-after the text appears in gedit, what exactly do i do so that the text ends up in my Download file. After its in my download file, i will just drag and drop it onto the video where it will embed itself!

Answer (score 1):

What the questioner probably meant:

- Movie files with hardcoded subtitles are nice.
- A movie file with seperate subtitle file(s) (e.g. srt), is even better - more easily adaptable.
- Zip is a practical way of packing and distributing a movie and seperate subtitle(s).
- Only one problem: you can't load the movie file from the zip and load the srt from the same zip in a viewer (Media Player Classic, VLC..). So you have to extract sth or everything each time.
- Hardcoding a subtitle (or a group of subtitles) in a movie means literally waiting all night for the result.
- Adding/extracting a (or several) subtitle(files)/srt(s) to/from a movie should take only a few minutes in any movie file format (keeping video and audio codec as they are - streamcopy - only adding the sub).
- We can pack several things in epub, which is in fact zip, and read it as 1 complete file. Why not sth similar with movies?
- Or: Add/extract movie text in the same relatively fast way you would add/extract the audio part i.o.w.
- Developers?...

Answer (score 0):

1. With archive manager installed, you can extract the zip file in any location. Later you can open it using gedit.
2. Make sure you have extracted the zip file with .srt or .sub where you have your movie file (Else copy from the previously extracted location to the movie file location)

In order to view subtitles, either drag the subtitle file onto movie file or right-click inside movie player and select subtitles from there.